# Remove key from CountTable in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

am I missing something or is it really not possible in Nim (1.0.4) to remove a key from a [CountTable](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html#basic-usage-counttable)? del() seems to be only supported for Table and OrderedTable.

Many thanks,

Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update: this has been marked as a bug, and fixed in [e895bf7](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/12600/commits/e895bf79161f4fa80e37c19eb78c97de9a166ae3).
>
> If you're on a Nim 1.0.6 setting a key to 0 updates the `len`of the table, thanks to [29b6dd6](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/commit/29b6dd6196ae73c96cf8beeace9e4ee2d3433bde).
>
> `CountTable.del()` is included since Nim 1.2.0

You can set the key you want to delete to 0:

```
import tables

var tbl = toCountTable("aaabbb")
## tbl is {'a': 3, 'b': 3}

tbl['a'] = 0
## tbl now is {'b': 3}

echo tbl['a'] == 0
## true
echo tbl['c'] == 0
## true
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that. In my case I need to get rid of the key, i.e. just setting the value to 0 is not sufficient. That's why I was looking for the missing(?) del()

Comment: Why you need that? Honest question. Because when you set a key to 0, it responds exactly as if you delete it: `tbl.hasKey('a')` is false, the return value is the same as never seen keys. I cannot see how would be different if you did a `del()`

Comment: You are absolutely right! I didn't see that because of another, unrelated bug in my code. Apologies and thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, tbl.len still counts the key with value 0, but tbl.key doesn't!? Just posted this in the Nim forum: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/5639#35021